# Changing SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem's tint color/text color

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-share-extension, ios8-extension

So for the last two weeks I have been working on my GitHub repo https://github.com/satheeshwaran/iOS-8-Features-Demo where in I tried to demo the Share extension introduced in iOS 8. I got to know the way in which I could add `SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem` to a `SLComposeServiceViewController` but I was not able to figure out how to  change the tint color or the text color of a `SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem`.

What I have did so far,

[image]

See in the above figure I would like to set the description and the My First Share to some color of my choice, also may be I would like to customize the font or something. I dug into the **SocialFramework** a bit but was not able to get anything out of it.

I saw Evernote's share extension on my iPad and it looks like this,
[image]

If you see at the bottom there is an icon and also the text color etc matches the theme of the navigation bar.

**Quoting the WWDC 2014 presentation on extension programming,**

> `SLComposeServiceViewController` for standard UI 
>   UI/`NSViewController` for custom UI
>   Coming to my question,

1. Can I customize `SLComposeServiceViewController` and `SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem` to look like this??
2. The second question is about the quote, can the default `SLComposeServiceViewController` be customized at all?? or should I go with a `UIViewController` subclass to do my own UI.
3. How would have Evernote done it custom `UIViewController` subclass to duplicate the behavior or using `SLComposeServiceViewController` ( I am not sure whether to ask this but I want answers)

Answer (score 6):

For customizing the navigation bar.
The normal, non-dot notation methods work fine for me.

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[self navigationItem] setTitleView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"elephant.png"]]];
```

For the `SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem` that does look like a custom subclass given the icon.

The only public methods for configuration on `SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem` 

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; // The displayed name of the option.
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *value; // The current value/setting of the option.
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL valuePending; // Default is NO. set to YES to show a progress indicator. Can be used with a value too.`

Answer (score 4):

My code, which i've used to get result similar to Evernote:

```
func getTopWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    if let img = UIImage(named: "icon.png") {
        img.drawInRect(CGRectMake((size.width-size.height)/2, 0, size.height, size.height))
    }
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let navSize = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(getTopWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), size: navSize!), forBarMetrics: .Default)
}
```

[image: SLComposeServiceViewController with custom navigation bar]

Comment: Great!! Any idea on the evernote logo kinda icon setting on the navigation bar?

Comment: @satheeshwaran added missing icon on navigation bar, hopefully will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the navigation controller of SLComposeServiceViewController is a SLSheetNavigationController, setting title view to its navigation bar seems doesn't have any effects, also the title text attribute.

Comment: Yes SLShettNaviagtionController does not behave like a normal UINavigationController too.

Answer (score 0):

I think proper answer here:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let table = textView.superview?.superview?.superview as? UITableView {
        let length = table.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        table.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: length - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)

        if let row = table.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)) as? UITableViewCell {
            row.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }
}
```

SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem just rendered in UITableViewCell which you can modify.